# what would happen to CRUD when you index on every column in a table in SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table in SQL database and put index on every column of it, what would happen to CRUD?

I think CREATE statement will definitely be slower and READ will be faster. But I don't know what about UPDATE and DELETE.

On one side, since there are WHERE clauses in UPDATE and DELETE statements, I guess that part will be faster. But since these 2 operations will also modify other columns, I guess that part will be slower. Then which part will count more and what's the final impact on UPDATE and DELETE?

Comment: Suggest some reading, e.g. https://redmondmag.com/articles/2014/07/16/too-many-sql-server-indexes.aspx#:~:text=The%20reason%20that%20having%20to,logged%20to%20the%20transaction%20log. there are many similar articles around

Comment: Why do you whant to add index to each column? I don't think this is generally a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE` will definitely be slower because every deleted row will require deleting the row from each index.  Of course, that is offset by any *increase* in speed based on the `WHERE` clause.

`UPDATE` might be slower or faster.  Filtering might be faster, depending on the `WHERE` clause.  On the other hand, every column bing modified would need index updates.

Comment: why is DELETE definitely slower while UPDATE could be faster or slower? Is it because for DELETE, the indexes of all columns will need to be updated but for UPDATE, only the indexes of columns that appear in SET clause will be updated?

Comment: @Daisy . . . That is the logic.

Comment: Then if the number of total columns in the table is limited, for example, if there is only one column, will DELETE be faster?